# Kinetic-energy conservation in gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, momentum, energy-conservation, work

If I take two objects A and B separated from each other as the system, when these two objects attract each other due to mutual force of gravity between them,Does the Kinetic-energy of the whole system remains same? If no, why? (As no external force is acting so $\Delta KE = 0$ from Work - Kinetic energy theorem).
Note: not a homework question, just a conceptual doubt regarding the usage of Work kinetic-energy theorem and conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering object $A$ as the system then the external force on the system is the gravitational attraction on object $A$ due to object $B$ and it is that force that does work on the system with the result that the kinetic energy of the system increases.
The same can be done treating object $B$ as the system where the external force on the system is the gravitational attraction on object $B$ due to object $A$.

Treating objects $A$ and $B$ as the system then the two gravitational attractive force are internal forces.
The two objects have gravitational potential energy and that is converted into kinetic energy of the two objects as they come closer together but although each object undergoes a change in momentum the two internal forces which exert equal and opposite impulses on the objects do not change the overall momentum of the system.

As the system of the two objects has no external forces acting on it, the centre of mass of the system does not move.

Answer (score 2):

The total momentum of the system remains constant because no external force is acting.

The total energy, i.e. potential energy + kinetic energy, remains constant because energy is conserved.

However the kinetic energy is not constant because kinetic energy and potential energy interconvert. As the two objects accelerate towards each other other the potential energy decreases and the kinetic energy increases.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we justify it using work kinetic energy theorem?